# Include config from different directory

Tags: scala, config, typesafe-config

I have the following files structure in the resources dir:

```
- resources:
| - dir1:
|   | - c.conf
| - a.conf
| - b.conf
```

`a` contain the following content:

```
a.conf:

   include "b"
```

I'd like to include `a` from `c`

How can I change the 'working directory' where the config loading runs?

If I will put this content in `c`:

```
include "../a"
```

`a` will be included, but `b` will be searched in `dir1` and not in the base directory

Comment: In that case it should be a bug, because in the [docs](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#include-semantics-locating-resources) it is mentioned that `if the included file is a relative path, then it should be located relative to the directory containing the including file. The current working directory of the process parsing a file must NOT be used when interpreting included paths.`

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: I don't have access to that project any more, but it is possible. try playing around with the absolute/relative paths, things like `"/b"` instead of `"b"`,